# How to add a function to jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What's the easiest way to define a new jQuery **member function**?

So that I can call something like:

```
$('#id').applyMyOwnFunc()
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Please see "[Defining your own functions in jQuery](https://web.archive.org/web/20091119233315/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/basil/archive/2008/09/22/defining-your-own-functions-in-jquery.aspx)" by [Basil Goldman](https://web.archive.org/web/20091119233315/http://www.deltaintegrity.com/en_US/executive.jsp?profile_id=1):

> In this post, I want to present how
> easy define your own functions in
> jQuery and using them.

Modified, based on the code in the blog post linked above:

```
jQuery.fn.yourFunctionName = function() {
    // `this` is the jQuery Object on which the yourFunctionName method is called.
    // `arguments` will contain any arguments passed to the yourFunctionName method.
    var firstElement = this[0];

    return this; // Needed for other methods to be able to chain off of yourFunctionName.
};
```

Just use:

```
$(element).yourFunctionName();
```

Comment: More than that, the article on the other end of that link isn't that great.

Comment: Yes and no. You should actually make use of the `extend()` function to be safe... There is an answer by RageZ that gives what I consider the correct answer.

Comment: `this` refers to the jQuery object, in this case its length is 1 because the selector is an ID which should be unique. Then you take the HTMLElement using `this[0]`. Then you rewrap it in jQuery with `$(this[0])`. Why?

Comment: @AlexisWilke Why should you make use of extend to be safe?

Comment: @xr280xr Because over time the interface (how to add new functions) can change. It could break your code when you upgrade to a newer version of jQuery.

Answer (score 35):

This is the pattern that I prefer to define my own plugins.

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.extend({
        myfunc: function(options) {
            options = $.extend( {}, $.MyFunc.defaults, options );

            this.each(function() {
                new $.MyFunc(this,options);
            });
            return this;
        }
    });

    // ctl is the element, options is the set of defaults + user options
    $.MyFunc = function( ctl, options ) {
         ...your function.
    };

    // option defaults
    $.MyFunc.defaults = {
        ...hash of default settings...
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Applied as:

```
$('selector').myfunc( { option: value } );
```

Comment: I think line 8 should be `new $.MyFunc($(this),options);`

Answer (score 19):

The [jquery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) has a section on [plugin authoring,](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) where I found this example:

```
jQuery.fn.debug = function() {
  return this.each(function(){
    alert(this);
  });
};
```

Then you'd be able to call it this way:

```
$("div p").debug();
```

Comment: what to do if I want to access the new method directly from $ like  $.newMethod() not its selector like $("dev").newMethod(), how to accomplish that?

Comment: $.newMethod = function(){ <insert function stuff here> };

Answer (score 15):

jQuery has the `extend` function to do that

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  check: function() {
    return this.each(function() { this.checked = true; });
  },
  uncheck: function() {
    return this.each(function() { this.checked = false; });
  }
});
```

you can see the documentation [there](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plugin, in it's simplest form...

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() {
  // do something here
};
```

You'll really want to consult the documentation though:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score -1):

```
/* This prototype example allows you to remove array from array */

Array.prototype.remove = function(x) {
var i;
for(i in this){
    if(this[i].toString() == x.toString()){
        this.splice(i,1)
    }
  }
 }


----> Now we can use it like this :

var val=10;
myarray.remove(val);
```