# How do I add a "core" function to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably a duplicate question, but I can't find it.

I understand " [How to add a function to jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768150/how-to-add-a-function-to-jquery)  " - with the activation of that function being something like:

```
jQueury(selector).myFunction();
```

But jQuery also has some "core" functions that can be activated like:

```
jQuery.ajax(options);
```

If I want to add a function to jQuery that does not act on an element, like a logging function, how would I be able to achieve adding it to the "core" so that it can be activated like:

```
jQuery.log('message');
```

Comment: Use [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) with only one argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$.extend( { functionName: function() { ... } } );`.

Or more simply: `$.functionName = function() { ... };`.

Answer (score 1):

So just define it:

```
$.log = function(str) { alert(str); };

jQuery.log('foo bar');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/4TAcv/

Comment: thoughts on this vs extend? Also isn't it best practice to use the full jQuery instead of `$` ?

Comment: @cwd: `$.extend` only appends one object properties to another, nothing else

Comment: "Also isn't it best practice to use the full jQuery instead of $" --- I always wrap my scrips into namespaces and use `$` inside

Comment: @zerkms: `$.extend()` with only one argument adds the object to the global `$` object. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: @zerkms single parameter `$.extend` assumes `jQuery` itself as target, and the parameter as the object to append.

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer: yes it does, so? **Any reason** to use `$.extend` for adding a single function?

Comment: @zerkms: by adding a property to the global `$` object, you can add functions to the jQuery namespace, which is what the OP wanted.

Comment: @zerkms but saying "$.extend only appends one object properties to another, nothing else" is wrong. `$.extend` *can* do more than just that and it does what the OP asks.

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer: what else can it do? It only takes properties from one (right, one or more) and puts to another (either implicitly or explicitly specified). "and it does what the OP asks" - cool, and why to prefer it over my advice? Any reason? ;-)

Comment: @Matt Bradley: I'm sorry, but I cannot see the difference between `$.extend()` and direct assignment in this case. Well, there is difference - assignment is more readable and shorter.

Comment: There is no difference which is why both ways are correct. And you're right about assignment being simpler: I never use `$.extend()`. However, `$.extend()` is useful for when you don't want to overwrite a previously defined property.