# how do I add a function to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, addition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a function to jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768150/how-to-add-a-function-to-jquery)

I want to add a function called parse_int to jQuery, which will simply return parseInt with radix 10. The function should be $.parse_int and work like $.trim (without an object). It will receive a string and return an integer. How do I add such a function to jQuery?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: why in heavens name would you want to do this?

Comment: @NullPointer: Well, not *exactly* a duplicate, since he wants to add a function directly on `$`.

Comment: sorry but i cant do anything now to undone my close vote ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. I added a JavaScript file called jquery_plugins.js , and here are the contents of this file:

```
// Add functions to the jQuery object.
(function( $ ) {
    // Return parseInt with radix 10 if not specified.
    $.parse_int= function(fp_string, fp_radix) {
        var radix= ((typeof(fp_radix) !== "undefined") ? fp_radix : 10);
        return parseInt(fp_string, radix);
    };
})( jQuery );
```

It works and the call is to $.parse_int with or without a radix. If the radix is not specified then the default is 10.

Uri.

Comment: That's NOT a plugin - its a utility! Big difference. Plugins get added to an *instance* of a jquery object. Utilities just add to the jQuery namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.parse_int(val){
    return parseInt(val, 10);
}
```

Comment: This code would add a "parse_int" method to an instance of jQuery, not the jQuery namespace itself. If the OP is looking for just a utility method, just remove the "fn" part.