# Jquery add validation function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an JS code validation like this :

```
if (theForm.chk_ccd.checked            &&
           (! theForm.ccd_pos [0].checked) &&
           (! theForm.ccd_pos [1].checked) &&
           (! theForm.ccd_pos [2].checked))
        {
          window.alert ('Please select data from the \"CCD Position\" field.');
          theForm.ccd_pos [0].focus ();
          return;
        }
```

Now I want to add that function into my Jquery JS function :

```
function ActionAdd (theForm)
    {
        $().ready(function()
        {
            $("#form").validate(
            {
                rules:
                {
                    de_no: "required",
                    de_name: "required",
                    product_name: "required",
                    plabel_no: "required",
                },
                messages:
                {
                    de_no: "<div class='error'>Please provide Part No.</div>",
                    de_name: "<div class='error'>Please provide Model Name</div>",
                    product_name: "<div class='error'>Please provide Product Name</div>",
                    plabel_no: "<div class='error'>Please provide Part No. (Pack Label)</div>",
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Anyone have an suggestions ?

Comment: You do not need that `.ready()` inside the `ActionAdd()` function.

Comment: Read [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768150/how-to-add-a-function-to-jquery) !

Answer (score 0):

```
function ActionAdd (theForm)
    {
            $("#form").validate(
            {
                rules:
                {
                    de_no: "required",
                    de_name: "required",
                    product_name: "required",
                    plabel_no: "required",
                },
                messages:
                {
                    de_no: "<div class='error'>Please provide Part No.</div>",
                    de_name: "<div class='error'>Please provide Model Name</div>",
                    product_name: "<div class='error'>Please provide Product Name</div>",
                    plabel_no: "<div class='error'>Please provide Part No. (Pack Label)</div>",
                }
            });
if (theForm.chk_ccd.checked            &&
           (! theForm.ccd_pos [0].checked) &&
           (! theForm.ccd_pos [1].checked) &&
           (! theForm.ccd_pos [2].checked))
        {
          window.alert ('Please select data from the \"CCD Position\" field.');
          theForm.ccd_pos [0].focus ();
          return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about window.alert ('Please select data from the \"CCD Position\" field.');, I add that into messages ?

Answer (score 0):

I think You need simple jquery validation demo to understand how it works.So here i have added
jsfiddle link.

HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="userName">
  <input type="text" name="userPass">
</form>
<input  value="Submit" type="button" id="submitForm">
```

JS
       http://jsfiddle.net/prWUn/

Comment: @Interval Grid You can find js and html in the mentioned jsfiddle link