# Applying function to a div by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I thought I was doing this right but its not working. I think I'm being stupid...

```
function expand(){

var wide = $(this).css('width');    
var high = $(this).css('height');

var newwide = wide * 10;
var newhigh = high * 10;

$(this).animate({'width':newwide,'height':newhigh}, 2000);

}

$('.object1').expand();
```

I just want to run this 'expand' function on the div with the class 'object1', what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a related question about adding a function to jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768150/how-to-add-a-function-to-jquery

Comment: function !==custom jQuery method: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery, to add a custom function, you do it like this:

```
(function($){

  $.fn.myFunction = function() {
    //Custom Function
  }

})(jQuery);
```

So, your code should look like this:

```
(function($){
$.fn.expand = function() {

var wide = $(this).css('width');    
var high = $(this).css('height');

var newwide = wide * 10;
var newhigh = high * 10;

$(this).animate({'width':newwide,'height':newhigh}, 2000);

}
})(jQuery);
```

### [Learn More](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-add-your-own-custom-functions-to.html)

Comment: Some mixed opinions here but this seems to be right from what I've read. And I can call it the same way as in my question? $('.object').expand();  ...right?

Answer (score 2):

Try to rewrite your code like this,

```
function expand($this){

  var wide = $this.css('width');    
  var high = $this.css('height');

  var newwide = wide * 10;
  var newhigh = high * 10;

  $this.animate({'width':newwide,'height':newhigh}, 2000);

}

expand($('.object1'));
```

Comment: Are you missing the brackets around `$(this)`? It's not a parameter.

Comment: @Shadowen Nope, that was intentionally left out. we are receiving the jquery object in a variable `$this`

Comment: Sorry, was written in a style I don't recognize! I'm so used to `$(...).click(...)` handlers. Can you provide a link to the documentation for this style in your answer?

Comment: @Shadowen This is just a normal function call with parameter. Don't confuse it. A variable name can be starts with $. It is all about javascript. No Jquery. :)

Answer (score 0):

How should the `$` object know it has a `expand()` method now?

If you really want a *jQuery plugin* here (that's what they call it when you attach something to the jQuery object), you have to attach it to `$.fn`:

```javascript
$.fn.expand = expand // as you defined it earlier
```

You almost surely don't want this. What creates what you were trying to achieve is giving the `$('.object1')` as a parameter to `expand()`:

```javascript
function expand($element){
    var wide = $element.css('width');    
    var high = $element.css('height');

    var newwide = wide * 10;
    var newhigh = high * 10;

    $element.animate({'width':newwide,'height':newhigh}, 2000);
}

expand($('.object1'));
```

Comment: Thanks. Why would I not want to do it the 'plugin' way? $.fn.expand = function... seems to give me exactly what I want, but if theres a reason why not then I can do it this way