# jQuery - Create a function and call it

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create a function in jQuery and call it?

This doesn't seems to be correct:

```
var scrollLink = function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top-20
        }, 300);
    };

    $('.js-ask').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('[href="' + this.dataset.target + '"]').tab('show');
        reportReadMessages();
    });

    $(".js-scroll").click(function(e, scrollLink) {
        e.preventDefault();
        scrollLink();
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't passing what is `this` in the `scrollLink()`. It is a function with empty parameters, when it doesn't understand what `this` is. So please change it to:

```
$('.js-ask').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('[href="' + this.dataset.target + '"]').tab('show');
    reportReadMessages();
});

$(".js-scroll").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top-20
    }, 300);
});
```

You are not passing the `scrollLink` in the right way. That's why it didn't work.

Or you can extend the function this way:

```
$.fn.scrollLink = function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top-20
    }, 300);
};
```

And you can call on the elements like:

```
$(this).scrollLink();
$(selector).scrollLink();
```

See [How to add a function to jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768150/how-to-add-a-function-to-jquery) for more information.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Yeah sorry I am just starting with jQuery. But your solution makes a lot of stuff more clear for me. Thanks.