# Re-populating a div when AJAX is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to re-populate a div after AJAX has finished with the updated values.
This is the AJAX code that I'm trying to use.

```
$(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function(){
            console.log("ajax complete");
            //so load your lightbox or JS scripts here again
            $( ".things" ).refresh();
        });
```

My console now says `refresh is not a function` which is correct. Because I haven't written a function. The thing is, I don't really know how to write a function to refresh the div `.things`. I hope someone here could help me?

I tried this:

```
function refresh {
    $('.things').load(document.URL +  ' .things');
}
```

But that give me a syntax error and I don't know if this is the right way to go?

Here is my console log.

```
S&F JS initialised script:125:4
ajax start script:110:5
ajax complete script:118:4
TypeError: $(...).refresh is not a function
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how you create a plugin in jQuery?

Comment: No I'm not asking that. I'm asking if someone know how to refresh the .things div using the example codes I gave. Because I'm stuck.

Comment: Ok. It was confusing as `$().refresh()` implies that you want to create a plugin.

Comment: Also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768150/how-to-add-a-function-to-jquery to add a function to JQuery.

Comment: there is a syntax error.  You need to write a function like this. `function refresh () { return 'whatever'; }` You have omited the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
$( ".things" ).refresh();
```

to this only:

```
refresh();
```

and just noticed you have missed or there is a typo here:

```
function refresh { // here you don't have () as functions requires these.
```

---

`refresh();` is a function not a method to bind on the selector.

---

As per your comment you can pass the selector in function's args and use it like:

```
function refresh($el){
    $el.load(document.URL +  ' .things');
}
```

now you can call it like:

```
refresh($('.things'));
```

Comment: But don't I need to tell the script which div to refresh?

If I change it to only refresh();  I get this:
`S&F JS initialised vaararrangementen:125:4
ajax start script:110:5
ajax complete script:118:4
ReferenceError: refresh is not defined
`

Comment: @Steggie `function refresh {` this is not a way to define any function. do you have any other error in console about it. Or can you confirm you have a correct function there?

Comment: @Jay: This worked. 
 `function refresh() {
  $('.things').load(document.URL +  ' .things');
 }`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are writing clean code but please remember refresh() is a user defined function not a predefined function.

So you just use below

```
 refresh();
```

instead of

```
$( ".things" ).refresh();
```

One more thing I noticed in your code. you omit to add () in your below code

```
function refresh {
$('.things').load(document.URL +  ' .things');
}
```