# $.function is not a function - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, chart.js

I realise this may be duplicate, the reason I am still asking is that a colleague has a line chart from chartJS. I copied his code, made it suit a bar chart and changed the ajax call slightly. The code is virtually the same, and I have done numerous checks for correct syntax. I am using the a slightly altered js script to call the jQuery function, but this still worked before I created my bar chart.

The script on the webpage is:

```
var url = '/stats/test-stats';

$('input[name="demographics"]').on('change', function() {
    console.log('changed demo to ' + this.value);
    if (this.value == '/stats/conversion-stats') {
        url = this.value;
        // console.log(url);
    }
});

$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
  opens: 'left',
  ranges: {
    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment()],
    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'),moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
}
});

$('input[name="daterange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
$.getBarData(url,'Average Dwell Time',picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$.getBarData(url,'Average Dwell Time');
});
```

I have seen about adding (jQuery) to different areas or ($), however my colleague does not do this and his works...

Here is my function that isn't a function...

```
   jQuery.getBarData = function(url='/stats/dwell-time-stats',label='',startDate='',endDate='') {
    console.log('called');

    function removeData(chart) {
        chart.data.labels.pop();
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.pop();
        });
        chart.update();
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            startDate: startDate, 
            endDate: endDate
        },
        success: function (d) {

            window.barChart.data.labels = [];

            window.barChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                dataset.data = [];
            });


            $.each(d.labels,function(k,v){
                window.barChart.data.labels.push(v);
            });

            $.each(d.recordsOne,function(k,v){
                window.barChart.data.datasetOne => {
                    //datasetOne.label = l[0];
                    data.push(v);
                }
            });

            $.each(d.recordsTwo,function(k,v){
                window.barChart.data.datasetTwo => {
                    //datasetTwo.label = l[1];
                    data.push(v);
                }
            });

            window.barChart.update();

        }
    });
};
```

As this is from chartJS the ctx, chart options and data are defined above that function, the whole script starts with:
        $(function() {'use strict'; /code here/ });

I would ask my colleague but they won't be available for a while. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Error Message:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $.getBarData is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (test_stat:206)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ test_stat:206
j @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error? There isn't an instance of `$.function` in this code. Also, `function` is reserved afaik. I doubt you can create a function called `function`.

Comment: provide exact error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a function to jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768150/how-to-add-a-function-to-jquery)

Comment: Sorry, forgot I said that, think of $.function as a general name. I meant $getBarData

Error:
jQuery.Deferred exception: $.getBarData is not a function TypeError: $.getBarData is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/stats/test_stat:206:7)
    at j (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:29999)
    at k (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30313) undefined

Comment: Is jQuery.js loaded in page more than once?

Comment: Yes actually, I threw it in when I didn't need to. But I took it out badly which was why I thought it was fixed. The duplicate jQuery was not the issue... I made a typo and am still receiving the same error

Comment: Was overwriting original jQuery object that had `getBarData ` as a property

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by my lack of understanding of chart.js

I was missing a needed function convertHex() that I assumed was created by my colleague and then just not used.

Basically syntax errors and missing functions led to confusing error statements.

Function:

```
function convertHex(hex,opacity){
    hex = hex.replace('#','');
    var r = parseInt(hex.substring(0,2), 16);
    var g = parseInt(hex.substring(2,4), 16);
    var b = parseInt(hex.substring(4,6), 16);

    var result = 'rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+','+opacity/100+')';
    return result;
}
```